# Как избежать дублирования кода в Си

Tags: c, дублирование

Допустим, есть такие структуры данных:

```
enum Color{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Black,
    White
};

struct Car{
    char* model;
    enum Color color;
    double engineCapacity;
};

struct Cars{
    struct Car *garage;
    size_t count;
};
```

Чтобы найти элемент с соответствующим полем `color` и `engineCapacity` в списке типа `Cars` есть две функции:

```
struct Car *findByColor(struct Cars cars, enum Color color){
    while(cars.count-- > 0){
        if (cars.garage->color == color){
            return cars.garage;
        }
        cars.garage++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

struct Car *findByEngineCapacity(struct Cars cars, double engineCapacity){
    while(cars.count-- > 0){
        if (cars.garage->engineCapacity == engineCapacity){
            return cars.garage;
        }
        cars.garage++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Видно, что функции практически повторяют друг друга. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избежать дублирования кода в этом случае?

Comment: Где вы видите дублирование? Похожи? Да. Вполне нормальные функции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализуем велосипед, аналогичный алгоритму `::std::find_if`:

```
typedef struct Car t_Car;
typedef struct Cars t_Cars;
typedef int t_Bool;
typedef uintptr_t t_Context;
typedef t_Bool ( * t_Predicate )(t_Context const context, t_Car const * const p_car);

t_Car *
FindCar_If(t_Cars * const p_cars, t_Predicate const p_predicate, t_Context const context)
{
    t_Car * p_found_car = NULL;
    size_t car_index = 0;
    assert(p_cars);
    assert(p_cars->garage);
    assert(p_predicate);
    while(p_cars->count != car_index)
    {
        t_Car * const p_car = p_cars->garage + car_index;
        if((*p_predicate)(context, p_car))
        {
            p_found_car = p_car;
            break;
        }
        ++car_index;
    }
    return p_found_car;
}

t_Bool
Match_Colour(t_Context const context, t_Car const * const p_car)
{
    assert(p_car);
    return p_car->colour == ((enum Colour) context);
}

t_Bool
Match_EngineCapacity(t_Context const context, t_Car const * const p_car)
{
    assert(p_car);
    return p_car->engineCapacity == *((double const *) context);
}

// Пример использования:
t_Cars cars;
// добавляем машины...
{
    enum Colour const colour = Red;
    t_Car * p_red_car = FindCar_If(&cars, &Match_Colour, (t_Context) colour);
}
{
    double const capacity = 0.5;
    t_Car * p_hp_car = FindCar_If(&cars, &Match_EngineCapacity, (t_Context) &capacity);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, дружище!

Answer (score 1):

Одним из способов, который позволяет сохранить ту же эффективность, что обеспечивает ручное кодирование каждого варианта функции поиска, является использование макросов.

Для реализации вашей программы потребуется пара макросов. Один для генерации имени и кода функции, другой для выражения сравнения аргумента поиска с полем структуры `Car` (если обойтись только полями для которых оператор `==` работает подходящим способом, то его можно опустить).

Если вы намерены разместить код функций поиска  в отдельном файле, то потребуется еще макрос, который производит прототип функции.

Вызов макроса генерации кода  с именем поля и типом аргумента поиска будет создавать код поиска по конкретному полю (это похоже на использование шаблонов (templates) в C++).

Функции созданные таким образом вызываются аналогично тому, как это делается в тексте вопроса, т.е. с аргументом поиска, соответствующим типу поля.

Вот пример из 3-х файлов (для того, чтобы показать общий случай).

В заголовочном файле определяются структуры данных и макросы:

```
#ifndef _CARS_H
#define _CARS_H

enum Color{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Black,
    White
};

struct Car{
    char* model;
    enum Color color;
    double engineCapacity;
};

struct Cars{
    struct Car *garage;
    size_t count;
};

// Макрос делает функцию с суффиксом в ее имени из названия поля поиска
#define MAKE_FINDCAR_FUNC(field, T) struct Car *findBy_ ## field (struct Cars cars, T value) FIND_BODY_CODE(field)
// Макрос для прототипа такой функции
#define DCL_FINDCAR_FUNC(field, T) extern struct Car *findBy_ ## field (struct Cars cars, T value)

 // выражение по умолчанию для сравнения поля с аргументом функции
 #ifndef CMPEX
 #define CMPEX(FIELD_NAME) (cars.garage->FIELD_NAME == value)
 #endif

 // тело функции
 #define FIND_BODY_CODE(FIELD_NAME) { \
     while(cars.count-- > 0){ \
       if (CMPEX(FIELD_NAME)) return cars.garage; \
       cars.garage++;\
     } \
     return 0; \
 }

 #endif
```

Вот так может выглядеть файл с функцией, которая ищет машину по имени модели

```
 #include <stdlib.h>

 #include "cars.h"
 #include <string.h>

 // используем strcmp() для поиска модели по ее названию, поэтому включаем <strings.h>
 #undef CMPEX
 #define CMPEX(x) (strcmp(cars.garage->model, value) == 0)

 // получим код с именем findBy_model
 MAKE_FINDCAR_FUNC(model, char *)

 // да, это все что нужно написать для создания новой функции
```

И теперь файл с main() и функциями поиска по color и engineCapacity

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 #include "cars.h"

 /*
   делаем функцию
   struct Car *findBy_engineCapacity(struct Cars cars, double value) { ... }
 */
 MAKE_FINDCAR_FUNC(engineCapacity, double)
 /*
   делаем функцию
   struct Car *findBy_color(struct Cars cars, enum Coler value) { ... }
 */
 MAKE_FINDCAR_FUNC(color, enum Color)
 /*
   делаем прототип
   extern  struct Car *findBy_model(struct Cars cars, enum Coler value)
 */
 DCL_FINDCAR_FUNC(model, char *);

 int main() {
     struct Car car1 = {"ford", Red, 2.5};
     struct Car car2 = {"reno", Black, 1.8};
     struct Cars cars;
     cars.count = 2;
     cars.garage = (struct Car*) malloc(sizeof(struct Car) * cars.count);
     *cars.garage = car1;
     *(cars.garage + 1) = car2;

     struct Car *car3 = findBy_engineCapacity(cars, 2.5);
     if (car3)
       puts(car3->model);

     enum Color color = Black;
     struct Car *car4 = findBy_color(cars, color);
     if (car4)
       puts(car4->model);

     struct Car *p = findBy_model(cars, "reno");
     if (p)
       puts(p->model);

     free(cars.garage);
     return 0;
 }
```

Если есть вопросы, не стесняйтесь, спрашивайте в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @VTT, вроде разобрался.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum Color{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Black,
    White
};

struct Car{
    char* model;
    enum Color color;
    double engineCapacity;
};

struct Cars{
    struct Car *garage;
    size_t count;
};

int equalColor(struct Car *car, uintptr_t color){
    return car->color == (enum Color) color;
}

int equalEngineCapacity(struct Car *car, uintptr_t engineCapacity){
    return car->engineCapacity == *((double *)engineCapacity);
}

struct Car *findByField(struct Cars cars, int (*equal)(struct Car *, uintptr_t), uintptr_t value){
    while(cars.count-- > 0){
        if ((*equal)(cars.garage, value)){
            return cars.garage;
        }
        cars.garage++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    struct Car car1 = {"ford", Red, 2.5};
    struct Car car2 = {"reno", Black, 1.8};
    struct Cars cars;
    cars.count = 2;
    cars.garage = (struct Car*) malloc(sizeof(struct Car) * cars.count);
    *cars.garage = car1;
    *(cars.garage + 1) = car2;

    double engineCapacity = 2.5;
    struct Car *car3 = findByField(cars, &equalEngineCapacity, (uintptr_t) &engineCapacity);

    enum Color color = Black;
    struct Car *car4 = findByField(cars, &equalColor, (uintptr_t) color);

    free(cars.garage);
    return 0;
}
```